# Showing similarity of a companion matrix and a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> If $A$ is the companion matrix of a monic polynomial $f\in K[x]$, with deg $f=n$, show explicitly that $A-xI_n$ is similar to a diagonal matrix with main diagonal $1_K,1_K,\cdots,1_K,f$.

Suppose $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots+x^n$. Then its companion matrix is given by:

$A= \left[
\begin{array}{cccccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -a_0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -a_1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & . \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & . \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & . \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -a_{n-1}
\end{array}
\right]$ and 
$A-xI_n= \left[
\begin{array}{cccccc}
-x& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -a_0 \\
1 & -x & 0 & 0 & 0 & -a_1 \\
0 & 1 & -x & 0 & 0 & . \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -x & 0 & . \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -x & . \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -a_{n-1}-x
\end{array}
\right]$.

Now what I am asked to show is that the matrix $A-xI_n$ is similar to the matrix:
$$B= \left[
\begin{array}{cccccc}
1_K & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1_K & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1_K & 0 & 0 & . \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1_K & 0 & . \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1_K & . \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & f
\end{array}
\right]$$

I think the idea is to find a non-singular matrix $P$ such that $A-xI_n=PBP^{-1}$ so that by definition the two are similar. I'm not sure where to start. Any hints?

Well I tried observing what happens if I choose $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+x^2$. Its companion matrix is: 
$$A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -a_0  \\
1 & -a_1  
\end{array}
\right]\text{ and } A-xI_n=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
-x & -a_0  \\
1 & -a_1-x  
\end{array}
\right]$$ and $A-xI_n$ is supposed to be similar with $B=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1_K & 0  \\
0 & f  
\end{array}
\right]$. If they are similar then their characteristic polynomial must be the same right? But $$p_{A-xI_n}=|xI_n-(A-xI_n)|=4x^2+2a_1x+a_0$$ and I don't thin this is the same with $p_B=|xI_n-B|$. This confuses me more because their characteristic polynomials are supposed to be the same right? Or maybe I'm missing something? Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: You don't want to prove the existence of invertible $P$ such that $A=PBP^{-1}$ but rather such that $A-xI_n=PBP^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes. Sorry that's what I meant.

Comment: Right, this was just a typo. Concerning your confusion, it may come from the following fact: when you compute $p_{A-xI_n}$, you consider $A-xI_n$ as a constant matrix, so that $x$ is a sort of parameter. So while computing $p_{A-xI_n}$, you should write something like $|XI_n-(A-xI_n)|$, where $X$ is the indeterminate of $p_{A-xI_n}$.

Comment: So you mean that the $X$ I should use to find $p_{A-xI_n}$ is different from the $x$ in $A-xI_n$? I tried doing that but still I get that the characteristic polynomial are different.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A$ and $Z$ are similar, then by the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem $f(A)=f(Z)=0$. Now define $Q=\begin{pmatrix}q_1 & q_2 & \dots & q_n\end{pmatrix}$ where $q_{i+1} = Zq_i$, $(i=1,2,\dots,n-1)$ and $q_1$ is an arbitrary vector such that $Q$ has an inverse. We need to show that $QA = ZQ$.

$QA = \begin{pmatrix}q_2 & q_3 & \dots & q_n & -a_0 q_1 - a_1 q_2 - \dots - a_{n-1} q_n \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}q_2 & q_3 & \dots & q_n & Z q_n \end{pmatrix} = ZQ$

Note that

$-a_0 q_1 - a_1 q_2 - \dots - a_{n-1} q_n = (-a_0 -a_1Z-a_2Z^2 -\dots -a_{n-1}Z^{n-1}) q_1 = Z^n q_1 = Z q_n$

This is the general way of finding transformation matrix if you happen to know $Z$. However, your claim is not true as you can see in your example.