# Similarity of a Companion Matrix to a Diagonal Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be the companion matrix of a monic polynomial $f \in K[x]$ with $deg f=n$. Show that $A-xI_{n}$ is similar to a diagonal matrix with main diagonal $1,1,1, \dots , 1, f$. I tried my proof in this way: We want to find $P$ so that $P(A-xI_{n})P^{-1}=D$, where $D$ is the diagonal matrix mentioned above. Equivalently, we can solve for $P$ such that  $P(A-xI_{n})=DP$. To be able to visualize this, I tried to construct such a $P$ for $n=2$. For $n=2$, we have $A-xI_{n}=\begin{bmatrix} -x & -a_{0} \\ 1 & -x-a_{1} \end{bmatrix}, D=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & x^{2}+a_{1}x+a_{0} \end{bmatrix}$ Suppose $P=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$. Then $b-ax=a$ and $-a_{0}a-b(x+a_{1})=b$. Solving fot $a$ and $b$, I get $a=b=0$. But this cannot be since I want $P$ to be invertible. I would want to know where I got wrong and I would want to ask for a hint as to how to approach this problem for arbitrary $n$. Thanks

Comment: What would the eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $f$ be?

Comment: I figured that the eigenvector would be $[-1,-x,\dots, -x^{n-1}]$

Comment: @hchengz Hence similarity doesn't hold!

Comment: So this means that the exercise isn't valid? I saw this exercise in Hungerford's book  and I tend to think that exercises in books can be answered/proved.

Comment: See my answer in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650082/showing-similarity-of-a-companion-matrix-and-a-diagonal-matrix/651163#651163